# Backend Save user fields

Tags: users, user-profile

I'm just trying to change a value of any field in the User Table in Craft 3.

Basically, say I retrieve a User by its ID and change the name and SAVE it...

```
$oneUser = Craft::$app->users->getUserById($user_id);
if ($oneUser){
    $oneUser->name = "robert";
}
//  $success = Craft::$app->users->saveUser($oneUser);
// $success = \craft\elements\User::saveElement($oneUser);
//Craft::$app->users->saveElement($oneUser);
// \craft\elements\User::saveElement($user_id);
```

As you can see, I tried many different ways, but I can't manage to properly make it to work.

In other regular Entry section, I managed to make it to work like this:

```
   $thisOrder->setFieldValue('orderstatus', 'approved');
   $success = Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($thisOrder, false);
```

But I don't find the equivalent saveElement in User type...
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Craft 3.7.21, this can be done as follows.

```php
$user->name = 'New Name';
Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($user, false);
```

Prior to Craft 3.7.21, it was necessary to call `setFieldValue`.

```php
$user->setFieldValue('name', 'New Name');
Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($user, false);
```

This assumes that `$user` is a User element and that `name` is a custom field on users.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much. As a matter of fact using elements->saveElement does the job exactly as if it was a "regular" entry element... I was searching too far ! :D Thanks again.